# My Jeep Wrangler won't start

Tags: battery, starting

My Jeep Wrangler 1995/4 cylinder/manual was stored for winter and I tried starting it today. It did not start and just made continuous clicking noises.
When I jump start using my daily car it is still not turning over. It cranks for a short time and stops. Please see the attached video.

https://streamable.com/qlrzth

I tried taking the battery terminals out, cleaned them thoroughly and attached them again. Is my battery completely dead/busted that even jump start won't help? Do I need a new battery?

Comment: Take it out and have it tested. This is the only way to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique for jump starting a vehicle depends on the diameter and length of the copper wires you use as jump leads.  Your starter motor needs a lot of current to make it work, so it needs very thick wires to carry the current.  If you look at the wires that go from the battery to the starter motor you will notice that they are very thick and they only have a fairly thin insulation on them, so they are mostly copper.

Cheap jump leads usually have a small diameter copper and thick insulation to make them look up to the job.  These jump leads can only be used to add charge to the flat battery.  You need to have them jumped across from the running vehicle to the flat battery for some time, like maybe 10 minutes or more before you can try to start the engine.

Expensive jump leads will have large diameter copper conductors of maybe 10mm.  These jump leads are capable of carrying the required current to the starter motor to allow immediate starting of the dead vehicle.

From what I hear in the video, it sounds like you have the type of jump leads that are not able to start the engine immediately and need leaving connected for a while before starting.  Try that and see how it goes.

Whether you get it started or not, it is a good idea to get the battery tested, because if it is near its end of life, you don’t want to find out when you are in a awkward location.

Comment: It was the jumper cables. Like you said cheap jumper cables do not carry enough amp to kick start starter on a dead battery. I bought new heavy gauge cables and let the dead battery charge for 12 mins. I measured 14 volts at battery and also at positive terminal/alternator body. This was to make sure that Jeep has good ground. I turned the head lights on and they were bright. Finally, gave the ignition and she started after a little stutter. I will now get the battery tested and replaced. Thanks a lot Howie.